# Can you make "categories" in a tkinter app

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

It's a bit tricky to explain, since I don't know what it's exactly called, but I'm currently making an app (I'm a beginner) and I wanted to know if, by clicking on a button, it could take you to a different "part" of the app.
For example, the program asks you to choose between two categories, like a movie or a show, and by clicking on one it takes you to a different part of the app, where it might ask you, for example, what kind would you like to watch etc and eventually displays several movies in the categories you selected
This example is unrelated to my app but it was to make what I'm trying to do clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def fun1():
   root.destroy()
   root2=Tk()
  #add buttons, categories here for movies

def fun2():
   root.destroy()
   root3=Tk()
  #add buttons, categories here for shows



bt1 = Button(root, text = 'movies', command=fun1)
bt2 = Button(root, text = 'shows', command=fun2)

bt1.pack()
bt2.pack()
```